# run a jar file (generated by ant) in command line

Tags: java, ant, jar, javac, build.xml

I have a build.xml file that works fine.
The problem is that the generated jar file, and I need to run it without 'ant run'

How can I run the jar file?
running with

```
java -jar Main.jar main.Main
```

gives me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService
```

This is how I'm creating the jar file (build.xml):

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
<mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile= "${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/${conf.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" classpathref="classpath" includeantruntime="false"/>
    <copy todir="${build.dir}/${conf.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${conf.dir}"/>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="run" >
    <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath"/>
            <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>

<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>
```

The "ant run" task works fine with this jar.
How can I run this project without ant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `java -cp Main.jar main.Main`, `-jar` is for bundled jars with a Manifest saying which class is to be used as the main class. What you're doing with `-cp` (and within your ant build file) is just putting it on the main path: you're specifying `main.Main` as the main class explicitly, not within a manifest.

You should also put the other jars on the classpath (e.g. `-cp lib/example1.jar:lib/example2.jar:Main.jar`). Depending on what matches `**/*.jar`, there may be a number of them.

Comment: Exactly: java -cp lib/lib1.jar:lib/lib2.jar:....:Main.jar main.Main solves - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
java -jar Main.jar
```

Have you checked that Main.jar does in fact include your `org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService` class?

Comment: Hi casey, gives me the same error (other .jar missed): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService Thanks

Comment: org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService is another jar file.
Problem Solved with `java -cp lib/lib1.jar:lib/lib2.jar:....:Main.jar main.Main`. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The neo4j.jars are missing at runtime. Add a classpath parameter like:

```
java -cp yourLibDir -jar Main.jar
```

Comment: It should be `java [-options] class` or `java [-options] -jar jarfile`, not both (see `java -help`). In addition, you need to enumerate the jars in the lib directory one by one.

Comment: Yes -cp shuold be right before -jar jarfile. But in my Java help it says: " -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>".

Comment: You had both `-jar Main.jar` and `main.Main`, that was the issue. Regarding the jars on the classpath, if you've not experienced the pain of *having* to add each jar one by one when you run an application on the command line, you haven't done enough Java yet ;-) or you've been able to use the right tools (e.g. ant). The help is mean as "directories of classes" and "zip/jar" files, separately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add -classpath xxx.jar in your command line