# how to create a bundled runnable jar using Ant

Tags: java, ant, jar

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806566/run-a-jar-file-generated-by-ant-in-command-line), but it didn't really solve my problem, so I figured I'd post a new one.

I need to create a runnable jar (runnable simply by double clicking) using Ant.  I have the following java code and build.xml file, which compiles the code just fine and creates a jar file, but when I try to run the jar by double clicking, i get a message saying "Could not find main class: HttpController.java."

I have the suspicion that my problem has to do with loading the external `Apache Http.jar`, as I have successfully built and run a jar for a project that is identical, except that it does not reference any external jars.

Here is my code:

HttpController.java:

```
package pack;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpMessage;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class HttpController {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpHost httphost = new HttpHost("localhost", 80);

        try {

            HttpMessage req = new HttpGet("/test.html");
            HttpResponse resp = client.execute(httphost, (HttpGet) req);
            HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    entity.getContent()));

            String line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // shutdown the connection
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

build.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <project name="Test" basedir="." default="jar">
    <property name="source.dir"     value="src"/>
    <property name="lib.dir"        value="lib"/>
    <property name="class.dir"      value="bin"/>
    <property name="jar.dir"        value="dist"/>
    <property name="main-class"     value="pack.HttpController"/>

    <path id="libraries.path">    
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="clean" description="delete old files">
        <delete dir="${class.dir}"/>
        <delete dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" description="build class files" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="${class.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${source.dir}" destdir="${class.dir}">
            <classpath refid="libraries.path"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}/${lib.dir}"/>
        <copy todir="${jar.dir}/${lib.dir}" flatten="true">
            <path refid="libraries.path"/>
        </copy>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${class.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.dir}/${lib.dir}/Apache HTTP.jar"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>  
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.6.0_31-b05 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: HttpController
Class-Path: dist/lib
```

**EDIT** build.xml has been updated as per Mike's answer.  Problem is still not solved.  Also posted contents of manifest file, as per Danation's answer.

Comment: @see http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=build-tools&file=ant-example.

Comment: @jayan is it possible to do this without any external tools?  ie by just using Ant and writing my own build.xml file?

Comment: There are questions/answers in SO about creating runnable jars using eclipse etc. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502960/eclipse-how-to-build-an-executable-jar-with-external-jar. I prefer one-jar as it creates a single runnable file. Intgrating to ant should take 10 minute. Then why not try and see the result?

Comment: `Class-Path` takes a list of filenames as documented. Not a directory.

Comment: @jayan exporting to an executable jar using eclipse is not what I am trying to do.  I need to generate an executable jar using Ant.  The ultimate goal is to be able to distribute the source and allow the user to execute the code simply by executing `ant` on the command line, then double clicking a jar file that gets generated. Additionally, I would prefer not to have to install an external tool other than Ant itself.  I need to know how to do this using only Ant.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you post an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 20):

Snip...

I have reworked your build.xml file to properly include the libraries in the jar file and in the Manifest classpath. I'm assuming that your "apache http.jar" file is a wrapper for Apache Core, and contains several other jar files in it for the apache client, etc.

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<project name="Test" basedir="." default="jar">
    <property name="source.dir"     value="src"/>
    <property name="lib.dir"        value="lib"/>
    <property name="class.dir"      value="bin"/>
    <property name="jar.dir"        value="dist"/>
    <property name="jar.file"        value="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
    <property name="main-class"     value="pack.HttpController"/>

    <path id="libraries.path">    
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="clean" description="delete old files">
        <delete dir="${class.dir}"/>
        <delete dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" description="build class files" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="${class.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${source.dir}" destdir="${class.dir}">
            <classpath refid="libraries.path"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${class.dir}/${lib.dir}"/>
        <copy todir="${class.dir}/${lib.dir}" flatten="true">
            <path refid="libraries.path"/>
        </copy>

        <manifestclasspath property="manifest.classpath" jarfile="${jar.file}">
            <classpath refid="libraries.path"/>
        </manifestclasspath>

        <jar destfile="${jar.file}" basedir="${class.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${manifest.classpath}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>  
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: I made the edits recommended.  A few things I had to change (there is no `${dist}` property, I think you meant `${jar.dir}`), but the build still returns the same error.

Comment: Please also include the directory layout of the jar file.  I'm wondering if the rt is upset that your class is in the default package.

Comment: I moved `HttpController.java` to the `pack` package (src/pack) and adjusted the build.xml file to reflect that, but the same error occurs.

Comment: If you moved it to a package, then you need to put the files in a sub directory. You also need to change your source code, but I'm assuming you have done that.  Please post the directory structure of the jar file when you get a moment.

Comment: I even tested it this time :).  If you still have a problem, you should run the program from the command line to see what the error is. e.g. "java -jar Test.jar". When I run, I get a socketexception since I don't have any services listening to port 80 locally.

Comment: @Mike I still get the same error.  I copy and pasted your build.xml file exactly (adding the missing `</project>` tag, of course).  Apache HTTP.jar contains all the necessary class files for the code I have implemented.

Comment: And when you run it from the command line, what is the exact message you get?

Answer (score 5):

Your `Class-Path` entry is wrong, you have to specify each jar file individually, you cannot specify a directory with .jar files (only directories with .class files)

This is documented in the [JAR File specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR%20Manifest) and explained quite nicely in the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

If you have two libraries name `FirstLib.jar` and `SeconLib.jar` your Class-Path entry should look like this:

```
Class-Path: lib/FirstLib.jar lib/SecondLib.jar
```

**Edit**:
Inside your build.xml this would look like this:

```
<jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${class.dir}">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${lib.dir}/FirstLib.jar ${lib.dir}/SecondLib.jar"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

Comment: I've edited my build.xml file to reflect this, but I still keep getting the no main class error.  For Whatever reasono, it is not recognizing the main class I have defined

Comment: Does your main class really have no package? Because that's what `Main-Class: HttpController` defines.

Comment: I'll update the above code.  originally it had no package, but I have added a package to it and still encounter the same problem

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a general solution for making executable jar files but this is the code I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  Any words or attribute values which are capitalized and separated by
  underscores are places where you add the data.

  Example: PROJECT_NAME, enter your project name
-->

<project name="PROJECT_NAME" default="jar" basedir=".">
    <!-- source code package -->
    <property name="src" value="SOURCE_CODE_FOLDER"/>

    <!-- classes folder (will be deleted) -->
    <property name="cls" value="classes"/>

    <!-- the directory of the jar file -->
    <property name="jar.dir" value="JAR_FILE_DIRECTORY"/>

    <!-- the jar file itself -->
    <property name="jar.file" value="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}-launch.jar"/>

    <!-- the fully qualified name of the main class -->
    <property name="main" value="PATH.TO.MAIN_CLASS"/>

    <!-- initialization -->
    <target name="-init">

        <!-- the class folder* -->
        <mkdir dir="${cls}"/>

        <!-- the jar directory -->
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <!-- compiling of files -->
    <target name="-post-init-comp" depends="-init">

        <!--
          turn all of the source java classes into class files
          located in the directory we made*
        -->
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${cls}"/>
    </target>

    <!-- creation of the jar file -->
    <target name="jar" depends="-post-init-comp">

        <!-- make the executable jar -->
        <jar destfile="${jar.file}" basedir="${cls}">
            <manifest>

                <attribute name="Manifest-Version" value="1.0"/>
                <attribute name="Ant-Version" value="Apache Ant 1.8.3"/>

                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main}"/>

                <!--
                  for some reason, this is needed for me in order
                  to have the jar function right
                -->
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${main}"/>

                <!-- Any other mainfest data is added here -->

            </manifest>
        </jar>

        <!-- remove the class folder -->
        <delete dir="${cls}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

I've used this structure to make many different executable jar files, plus it is simpler than what you had :-)

All data put in the manifest tags under the jar tags will become an automatically generated manifest file with the given data.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your manifest file, it's most likely an issue in there.  I've only seen that error when the manifest file is incorrect.

Just speculation, but I think it's trying to run a ".java" file as it's main class, which isn't going to work.

See the oracle tutorial:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html.

If that doesn't help at all, post the contents of your manifest file as well as the directory structure of the .jar file in your original question.

Comment: I know there is a problem with the manifest file, but I need to know how to reconfigure build.xml so that ant generates it properly.

Comment: @ewok: Post the contents of your manifest file as well as the directory structure of the .jar file in your original question.  Once the problem is identified, you should have a better idea of where the problem in the build.xml is.