# Eclipse - How to clear the list of main files when creating a runnable jar

Tags: eclipse, executable-jar

Whenever I want to export a project of mine to a runnable jar it asks for the main class, but the problem is that there is every main class I ever created (and by now deleted a long time ago) in the list blowing the list up like crazy... How do I delete the cache or what ever for this list?

Comment: Is this the `Launch Configuration` combo you are talking about or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to do this more often then you should automate it.

I recommend creating a script for that. You can generate runnable jars with Ant and Maven alike. It is not a big deal. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874550/how-to-create-a-bundled-runnable-jar-using-ant) for Ant using the `manifest` element of the `jar` task, or see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven) for Maven using the `maven-assembly-plugin`.